# why do I get a connection reset when trying to access the spark master webUI?

Tags: apache-spark, installation, centos8, webui

I am trying to install a spark stand-alone-cluster on CentOS8 and keep getting a connection reset when trying to access the webUI of the master after I start it. Am I missing something? Help please.

I have:

1. installed java:

`openjdk version "1.8.0_302" OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_302-b08) OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.302-b08, mixed mode)`

2. Installed scala:

   Scala code runner version 2.10.6 -- Copyright 2002-2013, LAMP/EPFL

`/usr/lib/scala -> /usr/lib/scala3-3.0.1/`

3. Installed spark:

`scala -> /usr/lib/scala3-3.0.1/`

4. configured bash profile with environmental variables in .bash_profile:

`export PATH=$PATH/user/lib/scala/bin export SPARK_HOME=/opt/spark export PATH=$PATH:$SPARK_HOME/bin`

5. opened up some ports in the firewall:

`ports: 6066/tcp 7077/tcp 8080-8081/tcp`

6. added config to spark-env.sh

`SPARK_LOCAL_IP='localhost' SPARK_MASTER_IP='spark-master' SPARK_MASTER_PORT='7077'`

7. started the master using start-master.sh
8. Using firefox to go to http://localhost:7077 - but keep getting a connection reset

Answer (score 0):

Spark master web UI port will be 8080 by default. Check at http://localhost:8080. You can change that using SPARK_MASTER_WEBUI_PORT env variable. [For your reference](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/spark-standalone.html).

Comment: Still getting a connection was reset message - 7077 is definitely open

Comment: Check the log file at $SPARK_HOME/logs. You should have below info lines if you master is up and running.      21/08/02 10:16:20 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'sparkMaster' on port 7077.
21/08/02 10:16:20 INFO Master: Starting Spark master at spark://<host>:7077
21/08/02 10:16:20 INFO Master: Running Spark version 2.4.5
21/08/02 10:16:20 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'MasterUI' on port 8080.
21/08/02 10:16:20 INFO MasterWebUI: Bound MasterWebUI to 0.0.0.0, and started at http://<ip>:8080
21/08/02 10:16:20 INFO Master: I have been elected leader! New state: ALIVE